# difference between flask and flask api

Tags: python, flask

I'm a novice to the flask web framework. I have few doubts
1. Can anyone tell me what's the difference between flask and flask api.
2. where do we use flask and flask api.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Flask API"?

Comment: The sad part is, i can really relate to this question. I had to spend such a long time figuring out the people telling me to build "apis" had no actual clue what they were talking about. An "api" is not inherently special, it's just guidelines to follow when you're trying to make two different programs communicate somehow. As such, "flask api" is not really a different thing. Flask can be used to make apis. api in plain language is just a means of communication between two programs. Hope this helps clear some stuff.

Comment: Are you asking about http://flask.pocoo.org/ versus https://www.flaskapi.org/ ???  You can never be too specific when asking a question.

Comment: @BareNakedCoder yes. its basically web framework v/s api

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you are asking about the difference between [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and [Flask API](https://www.flaskapi.org/#example).

[Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) is a web framework for Python. You can build websites using Python.

[Flask API](https://www.flaskapi.org/#example) can be used to create your own web API using Flask/Python. I think of an API (Application Programming Interface) as a door to data a developer is willing to share to those with a key. Send the key, they key is checked, and if correct, the data requested is sent back. Tons of companies have APIs including Google, Facebook, etc. Here's a good [article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/what-is-an-api-in-english-please-b880a3214a82) about it.

Hope that helped!

Comment: You can build your own web API with Flask as well, so the explanation for "Flask API" (the website is down) doesn't motivate when/why you'd use that instead of plain old vanilla "Flask".

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are Python web frameworks.

Flask provides basic options for web development like routing and template rendering etc while Flask API is an extension of Flask which focuses specifically on building RESTful APIs. It has all the capabilities of Flask and provides additional functionality such as input validation and parsing requests.